# Verify for text on windows application from AutoIT

Tags: autoit, windows

I have a automating a Windows application using AutoIT tool. 
I have done the scripting now I need a command by which I can verify that the particular text on the application?

For eg: I open the application,
then I execute the some task.
Once task is compelete success is displayed on the application screen.
I want to verify wheather success was displayed when task was completed.

Let me know how this can be done through AutoIT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that depends alot how the application is designed. with autoit for most windows-based uis, you can use the autoit window info tool to inspect elements, then with that info, get the control's text or value with

controlGetText [1]

```
#include <MsgBoxConstants.au3>

Example()

Func Example()
    ; Run Notepad
    Run("notepad.exe")

    ; Wait 10 seconds for the Notepad window to appear.
    Local $hWnd = WinWait("[CLASS:Notepad]", "", 10)

    ; Set the edit control in Notepad with some text. The handle returned by WinWait is used for the "title" parameter of ControlSetText.
    ControlSetText($hWnd, "", "Edit1", "This is some text")

    ; Retrieve the text of the edit control in Notepad. The handle returned by WinWait is used for the "title" parameter of ControlGetText.
    Local $sText = ControlGetText($hWnd, "", "Edit1")

    ; Display the text of the edit control.
    MsgBox($MB_SYSTEMMODAL, "", "The text in Edit1 is: " & $sText)

    ; Close the Notepad window using the handle returned by WinWait.
    WinClose($hWnd)
EndFunc   ;==>Example
```

Start with that and let me know if you need more help!

[1] https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/ControlGetText.htm

Comment: you can resolve your question and mark this as the correct answer then. Thank you and have a nice day